# Why isn't my BS scraper iterating across rows of the html table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a simple table using Beautiful Soup. Here is the html table I am scraping (in ascii):

```
  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason    Miller   42             4             25
1      Molly  Jacobson   52            24             94
2       Tina       Ali   36            31             57
3       Jake    Milner   24             2             62
4        Amy     Cooze   73             3             70
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c8eedd8bf41098a8940b/raw/c7e01a76d753f6e8700b54821e26ee5dde3199ab/gistfile1.txt'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = soup.find(class_='dataframe')

first_name = []
last_name = []
age = []
preTestScore = []
postTestScore = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    col = table.find_all('td')

    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    first_name.append(column_1)

    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    last_name.append(column_2)

    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    age.append(column_3)

    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    preTestScore.append(column_4)

    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    postTestScore.append(column_5)

columns = {'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name, 'age': age, 'preTestScore': preTestScore, 'postTestScore': postTestScore}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
print(df)
```

However, this is the resulting dataframe. I don't understand why my scraper isn't moving past the first row of the html table.

```
  age first_name last_name postTestScore preTestScore
0  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
1  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
2  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
3  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
4  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
5  42      Jason    Miller            25            4
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the working code:

```
first_name = []
last_name = []
age = []
preTestScore = []
postTestScore = []

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')

    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    first_name.append(column_1)

    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    last_name.append(column_2)

    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    age.append(column_3)

    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    preTestScore.append(column_4)

    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    postTestScore.append(column_5)

columns = {'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name, 'age': age, 'preTestScore': preTestScore, 'postTestScore': postTestScore}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
df
```

Comment: shouldn't `col = table.find_all('td')` be `row.find_all('td')` ?

Comment: Are you aware of the `read_html` function?  Try `pd.read_html(url)`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just getting the first `<td>` of the table and getting the values out of it on every iteration.

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    col = table.find_all('td')
```

should be:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all('td')
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got a related question. I am now getting this error:

---> 10     column_1 = col[1].string.strip()

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The first row in the table doesn't contain any `<td>` elements, only `<th>` ones. The `col` array is empty in the loop's first iteration, so you can't (and don't want to) extract any data from it.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the proper line: `for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:`